# A simpler markdown converter for node.js

Tags: node.js, markdown

I have a [`node.js`](http://nodejs.org/) app and I want to allow my users to enhance their messages with a little markdown. But only a little. I want

- Sanitization
- Bold (**) and Italics (*)
- Links

And that's about it, nothing more. But I may need more later, when extending the messaging system.

I've looked at `showdown`, `markdown-js` and `PageDown`. Only the latter had sanitising, but all of them are not configurable. `PageDown` was most promising, but I couldn't get it to not produce `<p>`'s around the output.

Is there some other alternative that allows me more control?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I want to extend the messages later, so I may need some additionally features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a rather new converter which supports direct access to the lexer. I think it will be what you need:  https://github.com/chjj/marked

Comment: So, how exactly do you tell _marked_ to not generate `<p>`...`</p>` around its output?

Comment: Marked does **not support sanitation**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Rho](http://npmjs.org/package/rho) project. You can use `InlineCompiler`, which does essentially what you need (assuming you also need some basic escaping like `&lt;` and `&amp;`).

You can use Rho inside Express/Handlebars helpers like this:

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var rho = require('rho');
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: {
        mdToHtml: function(options) {
            return new hbs.handlebars.SafeString(
                rho.toInlineHtml(options.fn(this))
            );
        }
    }
});
```

and then read the markdown from JSON inside templates, like

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p class="body">
        {{#mdToHtml}}{{message.body}}{{/mdToHtml}}
    </p>
</div>
```

where `message` is some JSON you have provided to the template.